# ¿Como abrir en un dataframe un csv delimitado por comas?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

tengo el siguiente problema, intento abrir un archivo .csv separado en ',' como dataframe, sin embargo al abrirlo e indicarle sep=',' el dataframe generado carga toda la información en una sola columna ¿Como podría abrir dicho archivo y dejarlo en un dataframe, incluyendo sus respectivas columnas.

A modo de ejemplo, la primera y segunda fila del .csv es el siguiente:

```
time,scenario,Emb_CANUTILLAR,Emb_CIPRESES,Emb_COLBUN,Emb_ELTORO,Emb_LMAULE,Emb_PANGUE,Emb_PEHUENCHE,Emb_PILMAIQUEN,Emb_RALCO,Emb_RAPEL

2019-09-24-23:00,path_h1956-1957,687.5213333333334,10.416733333333333,880.4633333333334,1289.2813333333334,409.70133333333337,62.62393333333333,119.23763333333332,215.17969999999997,879.0656666666666,418.7741
```

Al abrir en un excel, cada fila se ubica la primera columna solamente.

El código que utilicé fue:

```
vfin = pd.read_csv(ruta+'results1.csv',sep=',', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)

vfin
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de una linea del csv, quizas tengas algun valor erroneo o la codificacion de caracteres no sea correcta

Comment: Listo Jose, agregué como ejemplo la primera y segunda fila del archivo .csv, gracias.

Comment: Pandas ya considera por defecto que la coma es el separador, por lo que `sep=','` no sería necesario. Prueba a quitarlo. De todas formas, tal como lo tienes yo creo que debería haber separado en columnas y el que no lo haga sólo lo explico si el archivo CSV no está usando en realidad comas, sino otro caracter que visualmente es muy similar. Pero francamente me parece también una idea descabellada.

Comment: Lo intente, utilicé el mismo código y omití el sep=´,´ y aún así no me separaba el texto en columnas.

Comment: estas seguro que el archivo que muestras es el que estas intentando abrir con pandas?

Comment: ¿Y no será que en tu CSV cada línea va encerrada entre comillas? Prueba a ejecutar lo siguiente en tu Jupyter: `print(open(ruta+'results.csv','rb').read(200))` y edita la pregunta para mostrar lo que sale.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto

`vfin = pd.read_csv('path/file_name.csv', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)`

Veo que estas usando jupyter notebook, entonces solo pon `vfin`

Comment: Hola que tal, te comento que utilicé su recomendación, sin embargo el resultado fue el mismo.                                                                                      `vfin = pd.read_csv(ruta+'results1.csv',engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)

vfin`

Answer (score 0):

No veo nada más en tu ejemplo de csv y una simple llamada a `read_csv` deberia ser suficiente

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: lectura = pd.read_csv('csv.csv')

In [3]: lectura
Out[3]: 
               time         scenario  Emb_CANUTILLAR  Emb_CIPRESES  Emb_COLBUN   Emb_ELTORO  Emb_LMAULE  Emb_PANGUE  Emb_PEHUENCHE  Emb_PILMAIQUEN   Emb_RALCO  Emb_RAPEL
0  2019-09-24-23:00  path_h1956-1957      687.521333     10.416733  880.463333  1289.281333  409.701333   62.623933     119.237633        215.1797  879.065667   418.7741
```

¿No será un fallo en `Jupyter`? ¿Has probado a ejecutarlo como yo en consola?

P.S. He creado un archivo llamado 'csv.csv' con tus datos de ejemplo, obviamente cambia eso por la ruta correcta de tu documento